# Checking if Zipcode field has value of 99999... $(this).attr('id') == 'zipcode' && ($this.val(99999)))

Tags: jquery

I want to check if Zipcode text field has value of 99999 but the way it's written now gives an error.

**full code:**
function validateStep(step){
        if(step == fieldsetCount) return;

```
    var error = 1;
    var hasError = false;
    $('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(step) +')').find(':input.req:not(button)').each(function(){
        var $this       = $(this);
        var valueLength = jQuery.trim($this.val()).length;
    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/; 
    var zipAllowed = ['pa', "ca"] ; 

    if(valueLength == "" || $(this).attr('id') =='email' && !emailPattern.test($this.val()) || $(this).attr('id') == 'zipcode' && ($this.val(99999)))   

    {
            hasError = true;
            $this.css('background-color','#FFEDEF');
        }
        else
            $this.css('background-color','#fff');

    });
```

The EmailPattern check works fine but I can't seem to assign specific values only for the zipcode?

Comment: could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Please post all related code. What is the `valueLength` variable's expected value and how is it defined? What HTML element does `this` reference?

Comment: $this.val() sets the value. You must do this I guess: $this.val() == 99999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form `$something.val('99999')` sets the value and always evaluates to `true` in a conditional statement (the return value is the jQuery object `$something`).

If you want to check/test the value, use something like `if($something.val() === '99999')`.

You can check multiple values in the following way:

```
var zip = $zipcode.val();
if (zip == 0 || zip == 12345 || zip == 99999) {
    $zipcode.addClass('error');
} else {
    $zipcode.removeClass('error');
}
```

Note that you probably want to use `==` for comparisons in this particular case (`'00000' == 0` is true and `'00000' === 0` is false). For further reading, see [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons).

Comment: Thanks to both you and Yogesh!

$(this).attr('id') == 'zipcode' && $this.val() == 99999) was the magic line

Comment: Gah.... one problem after another.. Why is it not letting me add more than one value?

$(this).attr('id') == 'zipcode' && $this.val()!=('5, 6'))

It seems to recognize 5 but not 6 and i've tried all sorts of combinations including ((5) || (6)) but nothing seems to be working...

Comment: @user2738207 Updated my answer. You need a complete condition on each side of the `||` or `&&` operators. `if(zip == 5 || 6)` always evaluates to true because it essentially means "if the zipcode is 5 or if 6 is true (non-empty)".